# How can I make a custom command run always with `when: always`

Tags: circleci

I have a circle config which includes the following custom command:

```
  remove-circle-ip:
    description: "remove current Circle CI box IP from inbound security group rules for DB"
    steps:
      - aws-white-list-circleci-ip/remove:
          tag-key: circleci
          tag-value: whitelistmeplease
          port: 5432
```

which I use in my job as follows:

```
jobs:
  test:
    docker:
      - image: nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.8-nodejs12
        environment:
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-2
    steps:
      - setup
      - install-python-deps
      - add-circle-ip
      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            poetry run coverage run --source='.' manage.py test 
      - run:
          name: remove circle IP
          command:  remove-circle-ip
          when: always
```

I'd like the step for remove circle IP to run even if the tests which run before it fail. I can't seem to figure out the syntax for this. Previously, I had just used `- remove-circle-ip` to run the command rather than putting a `run` block, i.e.:

```
jobs:
  test:
    docker:
      ...
    steps:
      - setup
      - ...
      - add-circle-ip
      - ...
      - remove-circle-ip
```

but couldn't figure out how to specify `when: always` if I did it that way.

But now, when switching to calling my command as part of a `run` block, it fails with `"remove-circle-ip: command not found"`

So how can I make this command always run even if steps before fail?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to CircleCI so there may be a better way to do this, or maybe this shouldn't be done at all, however something similar was done (before I joined) to a project I'm working on. It was achieved by making every step report success, whether it actually succeeded or failed, which allows the command at the end to always run. The commands are all terminal commands, so they just have `|| true` at the end. I'm not sure how you would achieve that with a more complex command or using a builtin command.

In our case the steps that can fail are optional and we don't care if they actually fail or not. However if you want to report the failure I think that you should be able to store the failure from a previous step somewhere, and add a final step that reports it.